# Setting Warm-up time and fixing different gap between cars among start & end of edges in SUMO

Tags: visualization, sumo, traffic-simulation

I am having two problems regarding setting up warm-up time and gap between waiting vehicles.

1. Is there an option in sumocfg, to extract results from excluding [0,10] seconds, but only [10,327] seconds?
   I need to set up an warm-up time or change the edges of vehicles.
   I used end time but did not use begin time option, because it does not match my intention.

```
    <time> 
        <end value="327"/> 
    </time>
```

2. Is there a way to fix this phenomenon, or should I just append edges? It relates to the result of stopping time and queueing_length.

[cars waiting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrdvK.png)
[cars waiting2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fn0z.png)

Also, this phenomenon of abbreviated(squashed) status also appears, is this a normal phenomenon?
[squashed car](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npD62.png)